# TeamCity Finish Build Triggers Hierarchy

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I am currently attempting to implement finish build triggers and snapshot dependencies to kick off builds anytime a dependency is changed. However, my build configuration is a bit complex. For example, I may have a build configuration that looks like

This Picture.

[image: This Picture]

I would like to have these 3 cases met:

1. Build D kick off build B and C, then have either B or C kick off build A. Making sure that B and C finish before A is triggered.
2. If build D is not run and B is run, then only kick off build A.
3. If build D is not run and C is run, then only kick off build A as well.

In other words, I would like these sequences of builds:

1. D->(B and C)->A
2. B->A
3. C->A

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to change nuget dependency versions during build or how to set up triggers in teamcity? (if both, you may want to consider splitting..)

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how to set up build triggers in a hierarchical  order. I rephrased my question so that this would be more clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything you want to implement is possible just using snapshot dependencies with one small exception - trigger A by either B or C.
There is a rule in snapshot dependencies - The build of this configuration will run after all the dependencies are built. That means we can use **AND** operation (trigger A by B and C) but not **OR** (trigger A by B **or** C).

So to trigger B after D you need to add snapshot dependency on D for B. The same for C.
And similar for other builds.

It's possible to use Kotlin DSL to customize builds triggering and it may help you to implement **OR** operation. But that is not out of the box feature of TeamCity.

Another workaround is to have 2 copies of A build. One of them will be triggered by B build (it will have snapshot dependency on B) and another by C build (it will have snapshot dependency on C).
To reduce duplication you may extract all A logic into a template. So 2 copies will have just different dependencies but everything else will be defined in the template.